How to keep key mappings from re-ordering when remapped
I'm trying to implement key mapping in my game and I'd like them to show up in the same order as the context.  This works on initial load, but when I remap some keys, close the game, and then relaunch the game, suddenly the remapped keys show up at the top of the list seemingly in alphabetical order by name.  I assume this is because these are the ones in the enhanced player input save file, but I don't know how to stop it from ordering them like this.
